# EF Core2.2: Scaffold-DbContext not working with named connection string in WPF project

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I want to work with EF Core 2.2 and Database first in my .net Framework 4.7 project. it works fine running this command:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "data source=dbServer;initial catalog=myData;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Database
```

but then MS puts down this warning:

> warning To protect potentially sensitive information in your connection string, you should move it out of source code. See  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=723263 for guidance on storing  connection strings.

So i thought I do as told and updated the script as follows:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "name=MyConnection" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Database
```

which results in this error:

> A named connection string was used, but the name 'MyConnection' was not found in the application's configuration. Note that named connection strings are only supported when using 'IConfiguration' and a service provider, such as in a typical ASP.NET Core application. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=850912 for more information.

The named connection itself works fine, I have tested that by commennting out the first line that was generated by EF core and making use of the second line:

```
//optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("data source=dbServer;initial catalog=myData;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework");
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString);
```

starting the program it can connect and display the data as expected. But I would prefer to have that setting alrady in Scaffold-DbContext.  Any ideas?

For completeness sake here's the app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
       <add name="MyConnection" connectionString="data source=dbServer;initial catalog=myData;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
 </configuration>
...
```

Comment: *"but then MS puts down this warning"* Where?

Comment: Is your .Net framework a console app?

Comment: @IvanStoev: directly above the line with 'optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(' in the generated class derived from dbcontext

Comment: @user10728126: it is a WPF app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> EF Core2.2: Scaffold-DbContext not working with named connection string in WPF project

Fact. Both error message

> Note that named connection strings are only supported when using `IConfiguration` and a service provider, such as in a typical ASP.NET Core application.

and [Scaffold-DbContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell#scaffold-dbcontext) command documentation for `-Connection` parameter

> ...For ASP.NET Core 2.x projects, the value can be *name=<name of connection string>*. In that case the name comes from the configuration sources that are set up for the project...

indicate that named connection strings cannot be used with `Scaffold-DbContext` command in "legacy" `app.config` (NET Framework) based projects.

So for `Scaffold-DbContext` you have to use the actual connection string. And named connection string here (where I guess was the warning):

```
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(
    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString);
```

Comment: Thanks heaps. I read that bit but unfortunately note carefully enough :/